# Delphi - Multi Array of Position

Tags: arrays, function, delphi

can you please someone help with this problem?

I defined data type:

```
TBod = record
X: Integer;
Y: Integer;
end;
TArrayBod = array of TBod;
TBoxPoints = record
StartPoint: TBod;
EndPoint: TBod;
end;
```

and the contents of the variable is:

```
var
Points: TArrayBod ;
begin

Points[0].X := 0;
Points[0].Y := 0;
Points[1].X := 200;
Points[1].Y := 0;
Points[2].X := 200;
Points[2].Y := 200;
Points[3].X := 0;
Points[3].Y := 200;
Points[4].X := 0;
Points[4].Y := 0;

end;
```

I need these values, write a function that will return TBoxPoints (Minimal Point and Maximum Point).
The result should look like this:

```
TBoxPoints.StartPoint.X := 0;
TBoxPoints.StartPoint.Y := 0;
TBoxPoints.EndPoint.X := 200;
TBoxPoints.EndPoint.Y := 200;
```

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: What should it do if none of the supplied points are in the corners of the box? give a point on a (which?) side, or the corner?

Comment: Do it with a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the points form a rectangle, or you explicitly want a [bounding rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle)

Our start X is the smallest X from among the Xs, similarly Y from Ys.
Our end X is the largest X from among the Xs, similarly Y from Ys.

We must start our search with some initial values, using MaxInt for the start means every possible number is smaller or the same size, so we don't have a problem if all our positions are large. Similarly using MinInt for the end means we cater for if all our positions are negative.

```
uses
   Math;

function GetBoundingRectangle( Points: TArrayBod ): TBoxPoints
var
   Point: TBod 
begin
   Result.StartPoint.X := MaxInt;
   Result.StartPoint.Y := MaxInt;
   Result.EndPoint.X := MinInt;
   Result.EndPoint.Y := MinInt;

   for Point in Points do
   begin
      Result.StartPoint.X := Min( Result.StartPoint.X, Point.X );
      Result.StartPoint.Y := Min( Result.StartPoint.Y, Point.Y );
      Result.EndPoint.X := Max( Result.EndPoint.X, Point.X );
      Result.EndPoint.Y := Max( Result.EndPoint.X, Point.X );
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is exactly what I needed. From the set of points to get the minimum and maximum point.